# How to check if string is a valid postgres name?

Tags: postgresql

How to check if provided string is a valid name in postgres ?
I know that it is possible to use any string as name when it is quoted, but I want to know is string can be used without quotes i.e. as role name.
I have idea to do it like this:
BEGIN; CREATE ROLE ; ROLLBACK;
Is is good idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `quote_ident()` which will quote a string only if necessary.

So if the "quoted" value is the same as the input, it's a legal identifier:

```
select quote_ident('foobar') = 'foobar'
```

returns true, however

```
select quote_ident('foo bar') = 'foo bar'
```

returns false.